# Change color of natTable rows based on an RGB value stored in the ModelObject

Tags: java, nattable

I am trying to change the color of the rows in my NatTable based on an RGB value stored in my Model Object. I have found information on how to set custom styles in my NatTable, but these all seem to use predefined labels, not ones based on dynamic values.

```
//add custom cell label to cells that contain value AAA in column 2
CellOverrideLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator 
= new CellOverrideLabelAccumulator(gridLayer.getBodyDataProvider());
cellLabelAccumulator.registerOverride("AAA", 2, CELL_LABEL);

// Register label accumulator with the data layer
bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
```

CELL_LABEL is a string that links to a prebuilt label.

Answer (score 0):

The styling concept in NatTable is based on the mechanism you already found. You attach labels to cells (typically for some special conditions) and register styles for that labels. This way NatTable achieves separation of styling and content.

As your approach is to keep styling information and data in one model object, you need to find a way to get that into NatTable.

Basically you need to register a label to represent your model object somehow. And then register a style for that label that contains the background color information of your model object.